# Web app manifest does not meet the installability requirements

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps

I try to make a progressive web app, but Lighthouse says, I don't have enough icons, here are the Problems by Lighhouse:

```
Web app manifest does not meet the installability requirementsFailures: Manifest does not have a PNG icon of at least 144px.
```

```
Is not configured for a custom splash screenFailures: Manifest does not have a PNG icon of at least 512px.
```

and there are two errors in the Fast and reliable "tab", but this shouldn't matter I think?

Here is my Manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "PWA Test Tutorial",
  "short_name": "PWA",
  "start_url": ".",
  "background_color": "green",
  "theme_color": "red",
  "display": "standalone",
  "prefer_related_applications": "false",
  "icons": [
            {
              "src": "testLOGO.png",
              "sizes": "512x512",
              "type": "images/png"
            },
            {
              "src": "192.png",
              "sizes": "192x192",
              "type": "images/png"
            },
            {
              "src": "512.png",
              "sizes": "512x512",
              "type": "images/png",
              "purpose": "maskable"
            }
          ]

}
```

Where is my Problem ?
Do you need some more Information ?
Thanks for your Attention

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `type` of your icons should be `image/png` (without a "s")

Answer (score 0):

Add `"purpose": "maskable"` in your array of icons in `manifest.json`

Example:

```
{
  …
  "icons": [
    …
    {
      "src": "path/to/regular_icon.png",
      "sizes": "196x196",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "any"
    },
    {
      "src": "path/to/maskable_icon.png",
      "sizes": "196x196",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "maskable" // <-- New property value `"maskable"`
    },
    …
  ],
  …
}
```